# image flicker ajax polling

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am currently using ajax polling to periodically get new data from a database and show it to a user. It works fine, except sometimes, the images fetched begin to flicker, and then the flickering suddenly stops. Here is the JavaScript that fetches the data:

```
function loadLog(){     
    $.ajax({
        url: "stream.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
$("#inner").html(html);         
        }
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 2500);
```

the stream.php file contains basic sql commands that check the database for new data. So these commands are called every 2.5seconds. If the post type is an image, it is accompanied by a statement such as: user_name posted a new image, xseconds ago. The statements never flicker at all, but the image does. Is there a way to stop the flickering of the image? (An interesting thing is that, if the database already has images, then only newly posted images flicker, whereas the old images do not. So if there are in total 3 images, two old and one new, the new one flickers, whereas the other ones do not,despite the fact that the entire script is being polled and not specific images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on same problem since last few days and i ended up in following sample code.

What you need is pass the last updated `time-stamp` to new request and according to that `time-stamp` find record between passed `time-stamp` and current `time-stamp`.

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>testing comet</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var Comet = function (data_url)
    {
        this.timestamp = 0;
        this.url = data_url;  
        this.noerror = true;

        this.connect = function()
        {
            var self = this;

            $.ajax(
            {
                type : 'post',
                url : this.url,
                dataType : 'json', 
                data :
                {
                    'timestamp' : self.timestamp
                },
                success : function(response)
                {
                    self.timestamp = response.timestamp;
                    self.handleResponse(response);
                    self.noerror = true;          
                },
                complete : function(response)
                {
                    if (!self.noerror)
                    {
                        setTimeout(function(){ comet.connect(); }, 5000);           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.connect(); 
                    }
                    self.noerror = false; 
                }
            });
        }

        this.disconnect = function() {}

        this.handleResponse = function(response)
        {
            $('#content').append('<div>' + response.msg + '</div>');
        }

        this.doRequest = function(request) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type : 'post',
                url : "index.php",
                data :
                {
                    'msg' : request,
                    'submit' : "Send"
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var comet = new Comet('./backend.php');
    comet.connect();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**backend.php**

```
<?php

    $filename  = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.txt';

    $msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : '';
    if ($msg != '')
    {
        file_put_contents($filename,$msg);
        die();
    }

    $lastmodif    = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
    while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) // check if the data file has been modified
    {
        usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
        clearstatcache();
        $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['msg']       = file_get_contents($filename);
    $response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
    echo json_encode($response);
    flush();
?>
```

All you need to do is replace `txt file time modification` with `mysql` query.

**sample code to replace txt file with mysql**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die(mysql_error());
$database   = mysql_select_db('stackoverflow')or die(mysql_error());

function get_date()
{
    $query = mysql_query("show table status from stackoverflow like 'last_update'")or die(mysql_error());

    $row = array();
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $row[] = $result;
    }

    return strtotime($row[0]['Update_time']);
}


$lastmodif    = isset($_POST['timestamp']) ? $_POST['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = get_date();

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif)
{
    usleep(10000);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = get_date();
}

$query_db = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update.created) AS DATE,last_update.* FROM last_update WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update.created) BETWEEN '".$lastmodif."' AND '".$currentmodif."'")or die(mysql_error());

$row_db = array();
$response = array();
while($result_db = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_db))
{
    $response['msg'][]       = $result_db['title'];
}

$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
$response['lastmodif'] = $lastmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
flush();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: nice! thanks, it worked out for me, out of curiosity, do you know why new information was flickering in the first place? I'd like your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is because you are replacing the HTML of the `#inner` div each time, therefore it's being re-rendered.

The most elegant approach would be to only fetch the new items (by passing a timestamp argument to stream.php, ie `stream.php?timestamp=X` and only return items in your feed since the timestamp and then `.prepend();` that content into the `#inner` div.

Another suggestion would be to load that content in a new, hidden div so it fully renders, then quickly show it/hide the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update only part of #inner. E.g. if image has not changed, update only text. If image has changed - replace it with new one. I think in this case you will not notice flickering effect. Also look at http headers for these images - there may be incorrect Expires, Last-Modified, etc. headers and browser loads same images several times.